# Turning off token store in Azure Mobile App results in KeyNotFoundException in client SDK

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

I am doing custom authentication and not using refresh tokens with Azure Mobile Apps.  I've turn on Authentication (using B2C), set it to "take no action" and everything works great.  B2C gets the login done for me and then I switch to custom tokens with my own claims and refresh process. So...

When I turn off the Token Store and call `LoginAsync` , I get an Unhandled Exception from the client SDK

`System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

I turn it back on and voila the problem goes away.

Do I have to leave it on?  Seems like overhead I don't need but I'm over my head in this identity stuff anyway.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this - we'll take a look. Most likely it's a bug in App Service. However, Azure Mobile Apps generally require the Token Store feature to be enabled, so I recommend leaving it on in all cases (I don't expect the overhead to be too bad). In fact, at some point we may even remove the Token Store toggle from the portal and just have it always on for all apps.

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  I understand it doesn't affect my costs, so I guess I should care too much.  I just always turn stuff off if I'm not using it so future changes don't bite me.  :)

Comment: I can leave it in just fine.  I just wasn't expecting the error.  My app has access to financial information and I have to go as far as deleting the cookies off the device as the last step after logging in, so as to not have the next person launch the app and have the webview appear and disappear after logging them in.  Oops! :)